# Why is ubuntu 20.04 not detecting pendrives?

Tags: usb-drive

I tried changing the ports. I tried with multiple pen drives. when I go to disks there aren't any Pendrive options showing up. what can I do?

here is a screenshot of disks with my pen drive plugged in :
[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 does detect pen drives. Probably there is a hardware problem.

Comment: but it used to work before. and i am using the same pc @Pilot6

Comment: Something is broken. A cable could be broken, etc.

Comment: my laptop is in perfectly fine shape...

Comment: My laptop detects pen drives. What is the difference?

Comment: could there be a way for a hacker to keep your laptop from detecting pendrives?f

Comment: There can be two reasons: 1) a hardware problem; 2) you did something with the kernel.

Comment: what is to be done in case 2?

Comment: It depends on what you did.

Comment: Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: and how do i quit grub if i want to use my pc because i dont know how to exit grub and the previous time i used grub i had to reinstall ubuntu because i didnt know how to exit it

Comment: 1. You can *Try Ubuntu live booted from the USB drive*, that you used to install Ubuntu. If it works, obviously it can see its own USB drive. Can it also see another USB drive or an SD card or some other drive connected via USB? 2. *While in grub* you can simply try off the power or reboot with ctrl+alt+delete (but don't do that when Ubuntu is starting or has started).

Comment: New UEFI based systems normally have an UEFI setting for USB that prevents booting as that is not "secure" So if you have UEFI Secure Boot on or off, you may still need to change another UEFI setting for USB full support or allow USB boot. If an UEFI update occurred, it could change UEFI settings back to defaults and you then have to redo them. I have to keep a list with my system of the changes I make in UEFI settings.

Comment: how to change the uefi setting? how to turn pendrive on?

Comment: turns out i had enabling pendrives turned off in bios settings. i enabled it and it works now.

Comment: so you were wrong @Pilot6

Comment: @butterfly, Thanks for sharing your solution :-) If you wish, you can write and 'answer' to your question and describe what you did and later on 'accept' (click the tick icon, when available). This can help other users to find your solution.